# Omitting blob columns in NHibernate log output

Tags: c#, nhibernate, logging, log4net, blob

I'd like to print out SQL statements in NHibernate log file without certain blob-type column contents, which really fill up the space and make the whole thing unreadable.

Is this possible somehow, e.g. to apply a filter on logged columns? 
Maybe another option might be setting a limit on the number of printed characters.

Update: NHibernate version is 3.1.0.4000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of NHibernate are you using? Since 3.2.0.Alpha1 NHibernate truncates strings to 1000 chars and byte arrays (blobs) to 128 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately upgrading to v3.2 (or 3.3) is not an option since FluentNHibernate which I'm also using hasn't caught up yet. Afaik its latest release is built against NH3.1.0.4000.

Comment: @henginy I'm using Fluent NHibernate without problems with NHibernate 3.3.0. There are some ways to get it working (e.g. binding redirect or building yourself).

Comment: Nice, then I'll also give it a try.

Comment: @henginy The latest NuGet package of Fluent NHibernate supports the latest version of NHibernate.  If you aren't using NuGet I highly recommend it.